# How can I duplicate the functionality of a Javascript confirm with an AngularJS service?

Tags: angularjs

I created this alert service:

```
class AlertService {
    msg = null;
    constructor() { }
    confirm = (msg) => {
        var self = this
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    cancel = () => {
        this.msg = null;
        return false;
    }
    okay = () => {
        this.msg = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do it to have in my controller something like this:

```
   alertService.Confirm("Confirm or cancel")
      .then(function () {
         ts.doDelete(es.exam.examId)
      }
```

Here's my html. Note that al is already wired to the AlertService.

```
<div id="alert"
     ng-show="al.msg">
        <div>{{ al.msg }}</div>
        <button ng-click="al.okay()">
            Okay
        </button>
        <button ng-click="al.cancel()">
            Cancel
        </button>
</div>
```

My problem with this is I know how to call the confirm() and pass it the message but how can I make the alert service sit waiting until the user presses the Cancel or Okay buttons in a similar way to when I use the javascript confirm to make a confirmation box appear on my screen?

Answer (score 1):

You have to return `promise` from `Confirm` method. And resolve it or reject on yes/no handlers.
http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Here you can find similar solutions:

- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2632-creating-asynchronous-alerts-prompts-and-confirms-in-angularjs.htm
- https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog